# returning media from any private Instagram user

Tags: php, android, instagram, instagram-api

i can get media from public user
but,can't get media from private user and my response is:

```
"meta": {
"error_type":"APINotAllowedError",
"code": 400,
"error_message":"you cannot view this resource"}
```

how can get media from private user?

Comment: It says in it why you cannot view it. It's how Instagram works. If it's a private account you can only view it if they allow you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access images from a user that has set their account to private.

To improve the user experience of your application, mimic the behavior that Instagram uses when you're trying to access an account that is set to private. You can catch the 400 code and display an error message to your user explaining why they can't see the media.

Comment: how can access private account?i need solution @Tom

Comment: Follow them and if they allow you to see their profile you'll be able to access their media.